# Adding Consecutive Elements of Array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Trying to add two elements of an array together, i.e

- [2,4,6,8,10,12] should return a new array of  [6, 14, 22] *(2+4, 6+8, 10+12)*
- [4,2,7,15,35,23] should return a new array of [6,22,58] - *(4+2, 7+15, 35+23)*

New, frustrated and cannot formulate a for loop properly to achieve the desired result.

My wrong solution I tried so far:

```
 var newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i<numbers.length - 1; i +=2) {
    newArray = numbers.push(numbers[i] + numbers[i] + 1);
    console.log(newArray);
  }
```

Comment: `numbers[i] + 1` should be `numbers[i+1]`.  When `i` is 0 in your first array, the original would be adding `2 + 2 + 1` (numbers[i] + numbers[i] + 1) when you want `2 + 4` (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]).  Also when you do '`numbers.push()`, you are adding an element to the numbers array.  I think you want to do `newArray.push()`

Comment: Thanks. I actually did realize on my own that I wanted newArray.push, but was stumped on [numbers + i]. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close:

```
let newArray = [];

const numbers = [2,4,6,8,10,12];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i += 2) {
  newArray.push(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy, assuming input will always be an array of an even length

```
const data = [4,2,7,15,35,23]
const length = data.length
const res = []
for(let i = 0; i < length; i+=2){
  var num1 = data[i]
  var num2 = data[i + 1]
  res.push(num1 + num2)
}
console.log(res)
```